# Django query error: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.timedelta'

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm gonna get records which person lives less than 1 month.

```
cnt = Personne.objects.annotate(
        duration=Func(Func(F('deces_an_grg'), F('deces_mois_grg'), F('deces_jour_grg'), function='make_date'), Func(F('date_declaration_an_grg'), F('date_declaration_mois_grg'), F('date_declaration_jour_grg'), function='make_date'), function='age')
    ).filter(duration__gt=timedelta(days=30)).count()
```

But it occurs error like this. What's the reason? how can I fix it?

```
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.timedelta'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    ....
Django Version: 1.10
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.timedelta'
Exception Location: /***/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py in get_prep_value, line 1832
Python Executable:  /***/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.7.1
Python Path:    
['***',
 '/***/venv/lib/python37.zip',
 '/***/venv/lib/python3.7',
 '/***/venv/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7',
 '/***/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

Comment: How about  `cnt = Personne.objects.annotate(
        duration=Func(Func(F('deces_an_grg'), F('deces_mois_grg'), F('deces_jour_grg'), function='make_date'), Func(F('date_declaration_an_grg'), F('date_declaration_mois_grg'), F('date_declaration_jour_grg'), function='make_date'), function='age')
    ).filter(duration__gt=30).count()`? its hard to give any suggestion as there is no model definition in the question

Comment: Try that. But there's an error like this.

operator does not exist: interval < integer
LINE 1: ... "general_personne"."date_declaration_jour_grg")) < 30 GROUP...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

you can make query current fields.